# Why is my material not working?

Tags: materials, node-editor

I'm currently creating a material that random mixes textures and it did turn black.[image]

The diffuse
[image]

The Alpha
[image]

The Node
[image]
[image]
The rest is just mixing of textures and messy groups

Comment: I will probebly remove as many nodes I can. The problem is probebly that the material is to complicated.

Comment: You need to share your blender file or screenshot all the menus with the settings of your material. I don't even know which renderer you are using :-) EDIT: Im guessing it's cycles, so to use an alpha texture, do this:
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayqmH.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayqmH.png)

Comment: The node setup appears unreadable to me (too small)

Comment: I did fix the problem by remove nodes. So I know that the problem is the amount of nodes some how. Probably not just the amount but also how they are connected.

Comment: The reason for the horrible resolution is that my temp screen is to low res to take any better screen shots.

Comment: Given that the image of your nodes is unreadable (and you are using node groups that we cannot even guess what they do), you are going to need to troubleshoot this yourself... Start by disconnecting nodes and see the result of each one and see at what point does the chain fail.

Comment: I did disconect abute 20 textur nodes and after that it worked